# Avoid retrieve items with "Delete date"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this 2 entities and when I retrieve the People entity, the Set only contains persons without deletedDates, JPA have any anotation for this? At now I'm using JPA Api to retrieve data from DB

**Person**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Date deleteDate;

    @ManyToOne
    private People people;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

**People**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
public class People {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String from;

    @OrderBy("id")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "people", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure JPA has a way of handling this (at least I'm not aware of it), but its implementations (at least the most popular ones) do. What implementation are you using, Hibernate, EclipseLink...?

Comment: @PredragMaric Hibernate and I fix the Person class name, sorry!

Comment: JPA doesn't support "logical delete" of objects so, as Predrag says, you're down to implementation specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Hibernate, one way is to put `@Where` annotation on the set of persons

```
@OrderBy("id")
@Where(clause = "delete_date is null")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "people", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();
```